# Page not found on deploying Django-nonrel to Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, django-nonrel

I'm a newbie to Google App Engine but have played around with Django in the past so I am trying to use Django-nonrel with GAE.

There's not much information online, but have followed these tutorials successfully:

http://blog.sidmitra.com/getting-up-and-running-with-django-nonrel
http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine

I have managed to get setup fine and can get the 'It worked' page on local. However, when I upload my project to the Google App Engine Server I get a page with the following:

"Nonrel-testapp
The page you requested could not be found.
Powered by Django-nonrel"

I have used the following to upload:
python2.5 manage.py deploy

What am I doing wrong?
Are there any guides for uploading your Django app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. On the production server DEBUG is False, so you won't see that little "It worked" page. Since you're not the first one who was irritated by this I've just added a custom "It works!" page which also shows up on the production server. Just update your testapp source to see it.